# Can you fill cracks in the side of a live edge slab

Tags: wood, wood-repair, adhesives

I have a couple of live edge slabs I was planning on making into live edge end tables but I'm wondering what to do with the cracks in the side - if anything can be done at all. Could I fill them with a glue/sawdust mixture? Would some other commercial product be better? Is it worth attempting at all?

Here are pictures of the cracks:
[image: Live edge slab]

[image: Live edge slab]

Comment: What did you end up doing?  Could you post pictures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could I fill them with a glue/sawdust mixture?

You can yes but common woodworking glue (PVA-type, white or yellow) wouldn't necessarily be the best choice for the glue.

A much more solid fill can be made by using epoxy. Filled (or just coloured) epoxy is now a common material for filling voids and defects in wood. To a degree this kind of filler can stabilise a crack and add strength, but without some further means to hold the wood steady (e.g. a butterfly key, hidden bolt or dowelling) a crack may continue to open up, so it is worth taking at least one extra step as a safety measure.

Further reading in some previous Q&As:
[filling cracks in tables](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/filling-cracks-in-tables)
[Large hole filler products, what is available](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/large-hole-filler-products-what-is-available)
[Filling gaps/seams in a new cherry tabletop](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/filling-gaps-seams-in-a-new-cherry-tabletop)

Answer (score 1):

Seconding the suggestion to use epoxy. That crack is an interesting one though because it goes through the nonflat surface of the live edge, so its a bit challenging to make a mould to stop the epoxy from leaking out.

[image: Epoxy pouring jig]

My suggestion would be to build a mould that holds the slab on its side (with the live edge on the top), and pour the epoxy in from the live edge. I did a [live edge slab project recently](https://www.danielplayfaircal.com/blogging/2021/02/20/new-desk-part-3-gap-filling-and-sanding.html) and built a somewhat similar jig for that purpose. In your case since the gaps are bigger I think it would be worth using a proper melamine mould (with vices holding it into the slab) to seal the crack on the flat faces.

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  Please do not provide links, insert photos instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an image.