# Making wood filler? - Pine + Glue

Tags: wood, filler

I want to make some wood filler for a pine cabinet.
Was just going to mix wood glue and Pine sawdust..
Is there any ratio or anything I should do before i go ahead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making wood filler from sawdust](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/making-wood-filler-from-sawdust)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to worry about a ratio, I suggest mixing it until its pasty, and it won't run.