# Drywall mud to patch bubbled veneer?

Tags: plywood, wood-repair, filler

The veneer on this shelf's plywood bubbled up.  I imagine there is not much expansion and contraction, so can I simply use drywall joint compound to fill this void once I cut the veneer away?  I purchased some Bondo wood filler, but I am not sure I want to deal with using it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Gypsum will absorb water and dry out repeatedly if the humidity is high.  That will affect the bonding of the gypsum to the substrate and the paint to the gypsum over time.  It might be better to choose a filler that is not as sensitive to water.

Answer (score 2):

If you must remove some bubbled laminate and then make flush by filling, then the Bondo would be a much better bet for you if the choice is only between these two options.

In addition to sanding dead flush far better (because of its hardness) it'll also be far easier to make flush in the first place since it doesn't shrink back like drywall compound (and almost all similar water-based fillers). So in essence it'll reduce filling time, *and* sanding time despite being so much harder.

There are other options as well, including but not limited to:

- epoxy putties;
- DIY thickened epoxy ([epoxy + filler material](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/large-hole-filler-products-what-is-available/3809#3809));
- Durham's Water Putty or similar.